# Comparison between Euler angles and Rodrigues rotation formula under small rotation hypothesis

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, rotation

Sorry for boring you during summer vacation, my friends. I am haunted by the comparison between [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) and [Rodrigues rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) under the small rotation hypothesis. Maybe, they cannot be compared because of the different ways of parametrization. Here are my comparison and analysis.

In the first case, after developping the explicit expression of Euler (Tait–Bryan) angle rotation matrix around $\theta_x$, $\theta_y$ and $\theta_x$, $\mathbf R_1$ can be given as
$$ \mathbf R_1 = \mathbf I + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -\theta_z & \theta_y \\ \theta_z & 0 & -\theta_x \\ -\theta_y & \theta_x & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
In the second case, following the 'same' small rotation hypothesis, the Taylor expansion for $\theta$ is performed on the Rodrigues's rotation matrix, and the approximated Rodrigues's matrix $\mathbf R_2$ can be expressed as
$$ \mathbf R_2 = \mathbf I + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -\theta n_z & \theta n_y \\ \theta n_z & 0 & -\theta n_x \\ -\theta n_y & \theta n_x & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\left[ n_x , n_y , n_z \right]$ is the unit rotation axis.

Thus, according to the 'similar' mathematical expression between $\mathbf R_1$ and $\mathbf R_2$, what physical meaning could we deduce between $\theta n_x$ and $\theta_x$ for example? Could one say $\theta n_x$ (the small rotation projected on $x$-rotational axis) is equivalent to $\theta_x$ (the small rotation around global $x$-axis)?

Furthermore, if the two expressions based on the different formula are equivalent in the physical sense. Does their time derivatives still to be equivalent? For example, the equivalence between $-\dot{\theta_z}$ and $-\dot{\theta} n_z -\theta \dot{n}_z$.

$$ \bf \dot{R}_1 =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -\dot{\theta_z} & \dot{\theta_y} \\ \dot{\theta_z} & 0 & -\dot{\theta_x} \\ -\dot{\theta_y} & \dot{\theta_x} & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$ \bf \dot{R}_2 =  
\begin{bmatrix} 0 &
 -\dot{\theta} n_z -\theta \dot{n}_z &
 \dot{\theta} n_y + \theta \dot{n}_y\\ 
\dot{\theta} n_z + \theta \dot{n}_z &
 0 &
 -\dot{\theta} n_x -\theta \dot{n}_x\\ 
-\dot{\theta} n_y -\theta \dot{n}_y &
 \dot{\theta} n_x + \theta \dot{n}_x &
 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

I cannot find a similar comparison in the textbook. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You should compare $\omega$. You can calculate  $\omega$ with $R_1$ and $R_2$.   $\omega_1=\vec \dot {\varphi}$  $\omega_2=\vec n \dot {\Tehta}$.

Comment: Again:
You should compare $\vec{\omega}$. You can calculate 
$\omega$ for $R_1$ and $R_2$  ,
$\tilde{\omega}=R^T\,\dot{R}$.     
For small angle, you get: 
$\vec{\omega}_1=[\dot{\vartheta}_x\,,\dot{\vartheta}_y\,,\dot{\vartheta}_z]^T$ and
$\vec{\omega}_2=\dot{\vartheta}\,[n_x\,,n_y\,,n_z]^T$

Comment: I forgot to mentions that 
The generalized velocities for Rodrigues Ansatz are:   $\dot{n}_x\,,\dot{n}_y\,, \dot{\vartheta}$